# JSF + Primefaces <p:selectOneRadio dentro de Datatable e Pagination

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:dataList value="#{simuladoBean.questoes}" var="q" type="unordered"
                rowIndexVar="qi" itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="1"
                styleClass="paginated">

      <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="color:#000;"
                        rendered="#{q.tipo == simuladoBean.certoErrado}">
                        <p:outputLabel for="resposta" value="Resposta: " />
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="resposta" value="#{simuladoBean.resposta}"
                            style="color:black;width:auto;">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{simuladoBean.processaResposta}" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certo" itemValue="Certo | #{q.id}" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Errado" itemValue="Errado | #{q.id}" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
     </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dataList>
```

Minha ManagedBean está como `@Named` e `@ViewScoped`.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
```

O código funciona normalmente porém, ao passar de uma página para outra (Paginação), quando eu retorno para a página anterior o `radiobutton` é desmarcado, o `ViewScoped` só não funciona para o `SelectOneRadio`.
Como mantenho o `Selectoneradio` como `viewScoped`, para que se marcar por exemplo certo na primeira página ao passar pra segunda e retornar para primeira o 'certo' ainda esteja marcado?

Comment: vc precisa deixar ViewScoped mesmo? Talvez o SessionScoped resolva seu problema.

Comment: Mesmo com o SessionScoped ele não funciona. Todos os atributos da ManagedBean estão ficando no scopo de view, apenas esse <f:selectoneRadio que não está.

Comment: Maroni me atentei a um detalhe, vc viu o import? nas minhas classes normalmente importo o "import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;" tenta trocar o import, deixando ViewScoped mesmo e me fala se funcionou. Abraços

Comment: Sim, os imports estão corretos, deixei eles ali na pergunta.   import javax.inject.Named; import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

Comment: Exato, no meu último comentário dei a ideia de trocar o import que está "javax.faces.VIEW.ViewScoped" para "javax.faces.BEAN.ViewScoped"